# Pull custom customer attribute and send in email? Magento 2.2

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, eav-attributes

I am working in Magento 2.2 and I am using an extension that allows the site admin to confirm new accounts before they are active.
The extension can be found here:
https://github.com/enrico69/magento2-customer-activation

When a new user registers the admin is sent an email that shows the email address of the new user.

This code sends the email:

```
 public function send($customer)
{
    $siteOwnerEmail = $this->scopeConfigInterface->getValue(
        'trans_email/ident_sales/email',
        ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
        $customer->getStoreId()
    );

    $this->transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier('enrico69_activation_email_notification')
        ->setTemplateOptions(
            [
                'area' => Area::AREA_FRONTEND,
                'store' => $customer->getStoreId(),
            ]
        )
        ->setTemplateVars(['email' => $customer->getEmail()]);

    $this->transportBuilder->addTo($siteOwnerEmail);
    $this->transportBuilder->setFrom(
        [
            'name'=> $this->storeManagerInterface->getStore($customer->getStoreId())->getName(),
            'email' => $siteOwnerEmail
        ]
    );
    
    $this->transportBuilder->getTransport()->sendMessage();
}
```

That file that emails the code to the admin is at:
https://github.com/enrico69/magento2-customer-activation/blob/master/Model/AdminNotification.php

And I believe line 70 below controls pulling the customers email:

```
 ->setTemplateVars(['email' => $customer->getEmail()]);
```

I also found the line below in https://github.com/enrico69/magento2-customer-activation/blob/master/Observer/UserActivation.php that prepares the code.

```
$newCustomer = $this->customerRepository->get($customer->getEmail());
```

I am trying to pull custom Customer attributes values added to my eav_attribute table. The attribute is "company_name" and is already created.
I found the following code which I modified here:
http://www.w3solver.com/magento2-addcreate-and-get-custom-customer-attribute-value/

So I created the line below in https://github.com/enrico69/magento2-customer-activation/blob/master/Observer/UserActivation.php

```
$newCustomer = $this->customerRepository->get($customer->getCustomAttribute('company_name')->getValue());
```

And added the line below in https://github.com/enrico69/magento2-customer-activation/blob/master/Model/AdminNotification.php

```
  ->setTemplateVars(['companyname' =>  $customer->getCustomAttribute('company_name')->getValue()]);
```

But this still isn't working.
Can anyone offer some clues to get me on the correct path? Thanks!

### EDIT: Figured this out and the answer is below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this working using the following code.

In the AdminNotification.php file at:
https://github.com/enrico69/magento2-customer-activation/blob/master/Model/AdminNotification.php

I replaced the following lines:

```
 $this->transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier('enrico69_activation_email_notification')
        ->setTemplateOptions(
            [
                'area' => Area::AREA_FRONTEND,
                'store' => $customer->getStoreId(),
            ]
        )
        ->setTemplateVars(['email' => $customer->getEmail()]);
```

With:

```
             ->setTemplateVars(
         [
                'email' => $customer->getEmail(),
                'company_name' => $customer->getCustomAttribute('company_name')->getValue()
                ]
         );
```

And in the frontend/email/new-customer-notification.html file at:
https://github.com/enrico69/magento2-customer-activation/blob/master/view/frontend/email/new-customer-notification.html

I replaced:

```
A new customer registered : {{var email|raw}} ! The account is waiting for approval.
```

With:

```
 A new customer registered : {{var email|raw}} Company name:  {{var company_name|raw}} The account is waiting for approval.
```

I couldn't find how at add multiple variables to  ->setTemplateVars anywhere so  I hope this helps someone! Thanks!